# Blender Exporting OBJ - material is not exported

Tags: textures, blender, .obj

I am new to blender so I don't know how it works properly.

Here is my story, 
I worked on a model and added material to it using the cycles render method.

[image]

Then I exported the project with these settings

[image]

To confirm that everything is right, I imported this model to a new blender

[image]

And I didn't get what I wanted

[image]

I wanted the materials to show up too

Does anyone know why this is happening, 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cycles uses a node based material system that is not compatible with most export options.

To have a material that can be exported use the blender internal material and texture settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can however export a single image texture with the obj without making a Blender internal material :

- temporarily switch to Blender internal
- enter Edit mode
- in the UV/Image Editor, select the image
- exit Edit mode
- Switch back to Cycles
- export

But you can't export multi-texture materials like Blender internal does.